# How can I (or should I) use pointers in my linked list

Tags: c++

I'm creating a Linked List program and I currently have this method to insert an item into the front of the list:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(T *o)
{
    node newNode;
    newNode.o = o;
    newNode.next = first;
    newNode.prev = NULL;
    first->prev = &newNode;
    first = &newNode;
}
```

where I have a struct as follows:

```
struct node {
node   *next;
node   *prev;
T      *o;
};
```

I think my logic is right for the insert method; however, I feel as if I'm not doing it properly, specifically dealing with the pointers.  I feel as if I have to many newNode.  lines and that I could do this better somehow.  Any suggestions or is it right?

Note: I'm new to C++ so please be kind.  I know this is a simple question

Comment: node * newNode = new node, could put rest in constructor, otherwise newNode is on the stack and will disappear when function returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newNode` is local to `insert()` and will be destructed when that method returns, meaning `first->prev` and `first` will be pointing to a `node` that no longer exists.

Use `new`:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(T *o)
{
    node* newNode = new node;
    newNode->o = o;
    newNode->next = first;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    first->prev = newNode;
    first = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Even though node is a struct? I thought that new was used for creating instances of classes?  But as I said, I'm new to c++ so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: `void LinkedList<T>::insert(T *o){ node newNode; }` Yeah, `newNode` is local variable allocated on the stack and it exists only within scope of this `insert(T *o)` function.

Comment: Yes. It would be the same for a variable of any type that is created on the stack: it is gone when the method returns.

Comment: @hmjd In C++, classes and structs are identical save for the fact that structs default to public while classes default to private. However, it is wise to semantically distinguish them.

Comment: And as Nosrettap says he is a beginner it would be worthwile pointing out that you shouldn't store pointers to T but T's instead for a generic linked list. Otherwise ownership of the T's is unclear and I bet they will never get deleted (or worse).